# Можно ли выполнить код smarty в php?

Tags: php, smarty

Всем привет! Столкнулся с задачей. Требуется выполнить smarty код в php файле. Имеется ли у smarty уже готовое решение, или нужно это делать в ручную

Comment: Готового решения к такому не находил. Можете найти код в скомпилированного `.tpl` и взять оттуда готовый `php`.

Comment: Это будет использовано в cms в качестве вывода новостей. Вместо {include file="news.tpl" title= $title} использовать {$news}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам не нужно выводить шаблон, а сохранить результат в переменную, можно выполнить

```php
$html = $smarty->fetch('template.tpl');
```

Comment: Нет, мне нужно компилировать код не из шаблона, а на стороне php $html = $smarty->fetch('{include...}');

Comment: Тогда вместо имени шаблона нужно передать объект типа `Smarty_Internal_Template`. Как это сделать - нужно поискать в исходниках смарти, т.к. внутри он преобразует имя шаблона в такой объект.